# C# LibVLCSharp player direct feed media

Tags: c#, vlc, libvlc, libvlcsharp

There is a C# application which uses LibVLC via NuGet packages.

These are the packages:

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/LibVLCSharp.WinForms
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows

With these packages it is very easy to drop some mediaplayers into your WinForms application.

All you have to do is to initialize a player and give a new `Media` to it:

```
LibVLCSharp.Shared.LibVLC libVLC = new LibVLC();

LibVLCSharp.WinForms.VideoView videoView;
videoView.MediaPlayer = new LibVLCSharp.Shared.MediaPlayer(libVLC)

videoView.MediaPlayer.Play(new Media(libVLC, "URL", FromType.FromLocation));
```

Now I want to feed the mediaplayer with my custom data from a buffer.
It can be byte-array, or anything similar. (data shall be considered to come from a valid mp4 file chunk-by-chunk).

How can I achieve that with libVLC in C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to create a Stream where not needed, you could also implement your own `MediaInput` class, and implement the required methods

https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp/-/blob/master/src/LibVLCSharp/MediaInput.cs

Then, the usage is the same as @mfkl pointed out. Be careful though, the MediaInput must be disposed!

```cs
this._mediaInput = new MyMediaInput();

mediaPlayer.Play(new Media(libVLC, this._mediaInput));

// At the end
this._mediaInput.Dispose();
```

Comment: Wow, this could be pretty new, I've even had to update the nuget packages to be able to have the MediaInput class available. Thanks

Comment: Yes it is new, I added this because I wanted to add more scenarios than just a plain Stream. Enjoy! 

Answer (score 6):

Use this Media constructor

```
new Media(libVLC, new StreamMediaInput(stream));
```

`stream` can by any .NET Stream.

This sample is with a torrent stream for example: https://github.com/mfkl/lvst/blob/master/LVST/Program.cs

Comment: whats difference  b/w StreamMediaInput & _mediaInput ?

Comment: StreamMediaInput is a concrete class provided by LVS. The MediaInput is an abstract class you can implement to define your own stream mechanism